# Are there jQuery Mobile Ranking Issues?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile, jquery

I recently rewrote a website using JQM. The Google Analytic sessions are now about half of what they were with the old site. Is anyone aware of ranking issues with JQM?

Answer (score 1):

The language, library or framework you use to create HTML has no affect on how Google ranks your site in search results. It is only the content, and partly the HTML, that affects that.

Now, that's not to say that jQuery Mobile doesn't put out lousy markup. From what I recall, the one time I (shudders) was forced to use it, I swore it off forever.

Comment: What problems did you encounter that caused you to swear? I did my share of swearing as well. What is your preferred front-end device independent development platform?

Comment: It's been three years, and I only used it for three months, but the only thing I recall is that it didn't interact well with regular jQuery and it had the same issues most of these things have; it will change regular markup and CSS without your knowledge or permission and can throw you into a tailspin. I don't know what a "device independent" development platform is.

Comment: I guess the term is "responsive" design.